# What is this on this hellebore flower?

Tags: identification, bugs

This hellebore flower has been eaten by some insect/snail. I'm trying to identify exactly what they are. I found the following brown thing (poo?) on the leaves. Would someone know what it is?

Thanks!

[image: Hellebore]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a rehydrated hellebore seed (which looks like mouse poo). Dont know which chewing insect is eating the leaves (caterpillar?)